# Bluetooth and WiFi drivers are completely missing

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I know this problem has been asked many times, and I know this, because I'm searching for solutions for months, but I couldn't find any.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04. As I said, bluetooth and WiFi are missing. And I mean they're completely missing, like my laptop doesn't have those options or anything related to them. Rfkill's list command doesn't show anything. All of those comments that'll give you some information about drivers don't show anything about bluetooth or WiFi. Nothing. Zero.

I specifically searched my problem with the laptop model, it turns out that the brand of the drivers(which is Broadcom in my case) does this on purpose, so people can't use their drivers. There was a solution with lots of votes on this site, it was saying "...download exe drivers and open with with an archive manager..." and so on. I did, but couldn't find the file they were talking about. So that solution basically didn't work, it was too complicated anyway.

I believe there's an easy solution for this, but I don't know what and it annoys me very much. I didn't do anything to lose them except switching to a different OS. I was using Windows, it was pure pain to use it. Now ubuntu works fine, but I don't have WiFi and Bluetooth.

Edit: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` command showed nothing.

Edit 2: `sudo lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09) 
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

And the output of `sudo lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0364 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ea7:0064 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` is empty. It showed nothing.

Edit 3: I just checked the wireless in BIOS and it says enabled.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wifi device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Let’s open up the hardware list a bit more. Can you include the output of `sudo lspci`, `sudo lsusb`, as well as the brand and model of your machine? This may make it easier to offer a solution 

Comment: Also post: `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Comment: We see no wireless or bluetooth at all. Is there a setting in the BIOS/EFI to enable/disable wireless?